# Making Excel Recognize Custom Day/Time Format

Tags: excel, excel-2007, excel-formula, excel-2010, excel-2013

I'm working with a date and time format from the Twitter API. It looks like this:

```
Tue Nov 26 20:44:15 +0000 2013
```

Is there a formula to convert this to a format that could be sorted chronologically? I don't need the +0000. Also not concerned about the day of week.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
=DATEVALUE(MID(A1,9,3) & MID(A1,4,5) & RIGHT(A1,4)) + TIMEVALUE(MID(A1,11,9))
```

Then format as you like. As requested you would want a Custom Format of `mmm dd HH:mm yyyy`

Answer (score 0):

Try this, assuming that your string is in A1:

```
=DATETIME(MID(A1, 5, 16) & MID(A1, 27, 4))
```

The two `MID` formulas cut out the parts of the string you want, namely the month, day, time, and year, but exclude the day of the week and the timezone.  This produces a string that the `DATETIME` function can automatically recognize and covert into a native Excel date format.

Comment: MID(C2, 5, 16) & MID(C2, 27, 4) does indeed generate Nov 26 20:44:15 2013, but DATETIME doesn't like that. Generates a #NAME error.